# Javascript : How why i get the .className 'underfined' but .html() work

Tags: javascript, classname

I know this question was posted many times but I can't understand my problem :

When I do :

```
alert($('#CalendarType').className);
```

I keep getting undefined in the alert, at start by searching on the web I thought it was because my div wasn't already load but I tried something else :

```
alert($('#CalendarType').html());
```

And this work.... I can't understand . If someone can explain me what I did wrong

Comment: "className gets and sets the value of the class attribute of the specified element." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className. You need "Gets or sets the element's identifier (attribute id)." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id.

Comment: `$('#CalendarType')[0].className`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(someSelector)` returns a jQuery object, not a DOM object.

`className` is a property of a DOM object, not of a jQuery object.

You can either extract the DOM object from the jQuery object:

```
alert($('#CalendarType')[0].className);
```

Or use the jQuery attr method:

```
alert($('#CalendarType').attr('class'));
```

Comment: You are missing closing bracket in second example

Answer (score 1):

You can use .attr() function instead. I am sure this will work:

```
alert($('#CalendarType').attr("class"));
```